# ¿cómo definir el valor de un select mediante una variable php?

Tags: php, javascript, html

Tengo el siguiente select de los meses del año y un input donde me muestra la opción seleccionada, quiero que aparezca la opción del mes actual seleccionada por *default* cuando inicie la pagina, para esto tengo una variable php donde defino en que mes me encuentro.
he buscado y no encuentro una solución. Hay alguna forma de hacerlo?

```js
var mostrarValor = function(x)
{ 
  document.getElementById('pseudonimo').value = x;
}
```

```html
<?php 
    $mes = date("m");
?>
 <select class="custom-select pull-right" id="mes" name="mes" onchange="mostrarValor(this.selectedIndex);" selected="<?php echo $mes;?>">
              <option value="01">Enero</option>
              <option value="02">Febrero</option>
              <option value="03">Marzo</option>
              <option value="04">Abril</option>
              <option value="05">Mayo</option>
              <option value="06">Junio</option>
              <option value="07">Julio</option>
              <option value="08">Agosto</option>
              <option value="09">Septiembre</option>
              <option value="10">Octubre</option>
              <option value="11">Noviembre</option>
              <option value="12">Diciembre</option>
            </select>

   <input type="text" name="pseudonimo" id="pseudonimo" value="" >
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una forma de coloca el mes actual al **select** desde PHP es mediante el siguiente codigo:

Donde:

```
<?php echo $select = ($mes =='01')? 'selected' : ''; ?>
```

Este bloque de PHP compara median un if el valor recibido para el mes actual y si el numero corresponde entonces coloca el **atributo** selected a **option**

Aqui esta la modificacion del codigo:

```
<?php 
    $mes = date("m");
?>


 <select class="custom-select pull-right" id="mes" name="mes" onchange="mostrarValor(this.selectedIndex);" selected="<?php echo $mes;?>">
              <option value="01" <?php echo $select = ($mes =='01')? 'selected' : ''; ?>>Enero</option>
              <option value="02" <?php echo $select = ($mes =='02')? 'selected' : ''; ?>>Febrero</option>
              <option value="03" <?php echo $select = ($mes =='03')? 'selected' : ''; ?>>Marzo</option>
              <option value="04" <?php echo $select = ($mes =='04')? 'selected' : ''; ?>>Abril</option>
              <option value="05" <?php echo $select = ($mes =='05')? 'selected' : ''; ?>>Mayo</option>
              <option value="06" <?php echo $select = ($mes =='06')? 'selected' : ''; ?>>Junio</option>
              <option value="07" <?php echo $select = ($mes =='07')? 'selected' : ''; ?>>Julio</option>
              <option value="08" <?php echo $select = ($mes =='08')? 'selected' : ''; ?> >Agosto</option>
              <option value="09" <?php echo $select = ($mes =='09')? 'selected' : ''; ?>>Septiembre</option>
              <option value="10" <?php echo $select = ($mes =='10')? 'selected' : ''; ?>>Octubre</option>
              <option value="11" <?php echo $select = ($mes =='11')? 'selected' : ''; ?>>Noviembre</option>
              <option value="12" <?php echo $select = ($mes =='12')? 'selected' : ''; ?>>Diciembre</option>
    </select>

   <input type="text" name="pseudonimo" id="pseudonimo" value="<?php echo $mes; ?>" >
```

Answer (score 0):

intenta comparar con cada opción el mes actual con el valor correspondiente y aplicarle ($mes==1)?"selected":""

ejemplo:

```
<option <?php echo ($mes==1)?"selected":""; ?> value="01">Enero</option>
        <option <?php echo ($mes==2)?"selected":""; ?> value="02">Febrero</option>
        <option <?php echo ($mes==3)?"selected":""; ?> value="03">Marzo</option>
        <option <?php echo ($mes==4)?"selected":""; ?> value="04">Abril</option>
        <option <?php echo ($mes==5)?"selected":""; ?> value="05">Mayo</option>
        <option <?php echo ($mes==6)?"selected":""; ?> value="06">Junio</option>
        <option <?php echo ($mes==7)?"selected":""; ?> value="07">Julio</option>
        <option <?php echo ($mes==8)?"selected":""; ?> value="08">Agosto</option>
        <option <?php echo ($mes==9)?"selected":""; ?>value="09">Septiembre</option>
        <option <?php echo ($mes==10)?"selected":""; ?> value="10">Octubre</option>
        <option <?php echo ($mes==11)?"selected":""; ?> value="11">Noviembre</option>
        <option <?php echo ($mes==12)?"selected":""; ?> value="12">Diciembre</option>
```

otra opción seria rellenar los option de la siguiente manera

```
//Establecer la información local en castellano de España
setlocale(LC_TIME,"es_ES");
$mesActual=date("m");
$options="";
for($mes=1;$mes<=12;$mes++)
{
  $dateObj   = DateTime::createFromFormat('!m',$mes);
  $monthName = strftime('%B', $dateObj->getTimestamp());
   $options.= "<option ".(($mesActual==$mes)?"selected":"")."value='".$mes."'>".$monthName."</option>";
}
echo $options;
```

Comment: Funciona muy bien la primer opción. Muchas gracias!